# way for div with border radius to have text not go ouside circle

Tags: jquery, css

I have no idea if this is possible, maybe there's a way to do this with just CSS or maybe jquery or jquery plugin.

When you put a border radius on div for example, and then you put text in that div, the text is contained by the div's original square shape, and overflows the circle created by the border radius.  Is there some way to have the circle shape do the text containing?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: how about adding `padding` to the div?

Comment: LOL this makes me think of the famous mug "CSS is Awesome"  http://laughingsquid.com/css-is-awesome/

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow: hidden` to the div with rounded corners.

Comment: this just makes it so you can't see the text when it extends past the circle, I'm trying to shape the text to the circle.

Comment: Sorry, misread that. +1 to `padding` in that case. I don't think you can wrap text around a non-rectangular shape with CSS or jQuery.